# How to make stylish pageviews counter using html and css?

Tags: html, css, styles

I want to make stylish pageviews counter for my site using html and css like which is in the given website:http://o2tricks.blogspot.com/,

if you know anything about it then tell me or give me link.

Comment: first you need server-side to count the viewes.  the display is very simple - every digit is inside single span, background image is the black/white and the number itself is bold colored white.

Comment: @GuyDafny how can I add each number in a span?

Comment: You use the server-side and some template.  You may do it using JS, but you need server side in any case, so why bother?

Comment: follow up my answer below just go through the sites which one you found best signup in  register your website 
and embed the given code and you are done no server side code hassle free and gives you all stats on your login too

Comment: 1999 called. They want their page counter back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some links for stat counters for website just signup embed the given code

- [Amazing Stat Counter](http://www.amazingcounters.com/samples.php)
- [GoStats](http://gostats.com/)
- [Stat Counter](http://statcounter.com/)
- [visitor hit counter](http://smallseotools.com/visitor-hit-counter/)

Comment: Thanks, but I want to use them for my database.

Comment: you just want good typography?

Answer (score 2):

here is some link for menu style

http://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeLinkEffects/

http://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeButtons/